# How to make a custom installer in install shield 2015

Tags: c#, installshield

I need a super installer to be created from InstallShield.

Following are my requirements:
The super installer will have the option to install multiple applications (For example: A, B and C).
If user selects only A and B, then A and B application must be installed. How can I achieve this with Install Shield

I tried Adding setup files as prerequisites it's not working.

I am trying to achieve a installer like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Installshield available to test, but if you have the more expensive versions of Installshield you can create "**[Suite Projects](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteCreatingSuites.htm#creatingsuites_1766868741_1049952%3FTocPath%3DCreating%2520Advanced%2520UI%2520and%2520Suite%252FAdvanced%2520UI%2520Installations%7C_____0)**" which are bundles of different types of installers run in sequence with various forms of logic available to control the installation process. I am not too familiar with it all, but check out the linked help content.

Look for Suite projects in the `File => New Projects` dialog - or equivalent. As I said, I don't have the tool available to check the exact details.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this article](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/332/the-difference-between-features-and-components/)

> For each optional component, you must create a corresponding feature
>   for it, then assign the component to that feature.  You then make each
>   of these features optional.  During the installation, the user will be
>   able to select or deselect each optional feature, which will in turn
>   and unbeknownst to him, select or deselect the component(s) that
>   belongs to the feature.

So, each app A, B C would be a component that you assign to its own separate feature which you create, and then the user can select the apps that they want.